# Attribute error for pool.map in Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

So I have this snippet of code:

```
def someFunction (S):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import time
    start = time.time()

    G = nx.read_gpickle("../../graphs/graph.gpickle")

    Ep = dict()
    with open("Ep.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.split()
            Ep[(int(data[0]), int(data[1]))] = float(data[2])

    pool = None
    def mapAvgSize (S):
        return avgIAC(G, S, Ep, I)
    if pool == None:
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)

    print 'Start Initialization...'
    S = []


    print 'Selecting S...'
    print 'before pool.map'
    Ts = pool.map(mapAvgSize, [S]*4)
    print 'after pool.map'
```

It looks like everything correct: I defined function before the pool, put everything under `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement. But unfortunately the above code goes up to the line `print 'before pool.map'` and then throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mapAvgSize'
```

The weirdest part is that the above code works under Linux, but fails on Windows (I wanted to test it outside my laptop on the computer with more cores).

Any help to figure why code fails on Windows would be appreciated and upvoted.

Comment: Your function definition's indentation level is off.. Move it up - below `someFunction`, at the same level as it

Comment: Then how do I provide G, S input parameters? If I move everything before pool.map up, then each worker is reading graph and Ep, and I want to read only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted, you need to make `mapAvg` a top-level function. Since it currently closes over some "local" variables, you need to fix this as well. You can either pass those currently closed-over variables using an initializer (`mapped` + `initializer` in the example) or pass them ain the iterable you're mapping (`mapped2`)

Example, demonstrating (some of) your options:

```
import multiprocessing


globalB = None


def mapped(a):
    global globalB
    return a * globalB


def initializer(*args):
    global globalB
    globalB, = args


def mapped2(args):
    a, b = args
    return a * b


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myB = 2
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5,
                                initializer=initializer,
                                initargs=(myB,)
                                )
    # Using the initializer provided globalB
    for i in pool.map(mapped, range(10)):
        print i

    # directly provided as an arg
    for i in pool.map(mapped2, ((a, myB) for a in range(10))):
        print i
```

In your code, you could of course move `Ep`, `G` (and whatever `I`) is to the top-level as well, but you'd cause file I/O per pool process, so I'd properly go with something like `mapped2` (using a dedicated queue item class instead of some tuple) if I had to implement it.

PS: The reason this even works on Linux (sometimes?!) seems to be an accidental outcome of how `fork()` works. You shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: Is there any particular benefit to use generator instead of a list for second pool.map?

Comment: Not really... At least not in the example.